# I already know that empty set is a basis for {0}. Then, can {0} be a basis for {0}??

Tags: linear-algebra

{0} is linearly independent and span{0}={0}. So I think {0} can be a basis for {0}.
If not, why??

Comment: It's not linearly independent

Answer (score 4):

Knowing that $\emptyset$ is a base for $\{0\}$
   suffices to rule
out that $\{0\}$ is a base .

Note that the definition of a dimension as the number of elements
in a basis is well defined.

If you know there is a basis with no elements this means that the
dimension of $\{0\}$ is $0$,

If $\{0\}$ would of been a base then the dimension would of been
$1$.

As said in the comments, the reasoning is that $\{0\}$ is not linearly
independent: $1\cdot0=0$ while $1\neq0$ so we have a linear combination
that sum to zero while not all scalars are $0$.